# Does not show error when registering on website PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have a database setup and I'm making a site where the user has to register with their username, email and password. However, for some reason, whenever I click on register without entering any information, it still registers into the database without showing the error. Here is the code.

```
<?php

// First we execute our common code to connection to the database and start the session
require("common.php");

// This if statement checks to determine whether the registration form has been submitted
// If it has, then the registration code is run, otherwise the form is displayed
if(!empty($_POST))
{
    // Ensure that the user has entered a non-empty username
    if(empty($_POST['username']))
    {
        // Note that die() is generally a terrible way of handling user errors
        // like this.  It is much better to display the error with the form
        // and allow the user to correct their mistake.  However, that is an
        // exercise for you to implement yourself.
        $username_error = "Please enter a username";
    }

    // Ensure that the user has entered a non-empty password
    if(empty($_POST['password']))
    {
        $password_error = "Please enter a password";
    }

    // Make sure the user entered a valid E-Mail address
    // filter_var is a useful PHP function for validating form input, see:
    // http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php
    // http://us.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.php
    if(!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
    {
       $invalid_email = "Invalid email";
    }

    // We will use this SQL query to see whether the username entered by the
    // user is already in use.  A SELECT query is used to retrieve data from the database.
    // :username is a special token, we will substitute a real value in its place when
    // we execute the query.
    $query = "
        SELECT
            1
        FROM users
        WHERE
            username = :username
    ";

    // This contains the definitions for any special tokens that we place in
    // our SQL query.  In this case, we are defining a value for the token
    // :username.  It is possible to insert $_POST['username'] directly into
    // your $query string; however doing so is very insecure and opens your
    // code up to SQL injection exploits.  Using tokens prevents this.
    // For more information on SQL injections, see Wikipedia:
    // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Injection
    $query_params = array(
        ':username' => $_POST['username']
    );

    try
    {
        // These two statements run the query against your database table.
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
    }
    catch(PDOException $ex)
    {
        // Note: On a production website, you should not output $ex->getMessage().
        // It may provide an attacker with helpful information about your code. 
        die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
    }

    // The fetch() method returns an array representing the "next" row from
    // the selected results, or false if there are no more rows to fetch.
    $row = $stmt->fetch();

    // If a row was returned, then we know a matching username was found in
    // the database already and we should not allow the user to continue.
    if($row)
    {
        $username_exist = "This username already exists!";
    }

    // Now we perform the same type of check for the email address, in order
    // to ensure that it is unique.
    $query = "
        SELECT
            1
        FROM users
        WHERE
            email = :email
    ";

    $query_params = array(
        ':email' => $_POST['email']
    );

    try
    {
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
    }
    catch(PDOException $ex)
    {
        die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
    }

    $row = $stmt->fetch();

    if($row)
    {
        $email_registered = "This email is already registered!";
    }

    // An INSERT query is used to add new rows to a database table.
    // Again, we are using special tokens (technically called parameters) to
    // protect against SQL injection attacks.
    $query = "
        INSERT INTO users (
            username,
            password,
            salt,
            email
        ) VALUES (
            :username,
            :password,
            :salt,
            :email
        )
    ";

    // A salt is randomly generated here to protect again brute force attacks
    // and rainbow table attacks.  The following statement generates a hex
    // representation of an 8 byte salt.  Representing this in hex provides
    // no additional security, but makes it easier for humans to read.
    // For more information:
    // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29
    // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_attack
    // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table
    $salt = dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)) . dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647));

    // This hashes the password with the salt so that it can be stored securely
    // in your database.  The output of this next statement is a 64 byte hex
    // string representing the 32 byte sha256 hash of the password.  The original
    // password cannot be recovered from the hash.  For more information:
    // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function
    $password = hash('sha256', $_POST['password'] . $salt);

    // Next we hash the hash value 65536 more times.  The purpose of this is to
    // protect against brute force attacks.  Now an attacker must compute the hash 65537
    // times for each guess they make against a password, whereas if the password
    // were hashed only once the attacker would have been able to make 65537 different 
    // guesses in the same amount of time instead of only one.
    for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++)
    {
        $password = hash('sha256', $password . $salt);
    }

    // Here we prepare our tokens for insertion into the SQL query.  We do not
    // store the original password; only the hashed version of it.  We do store
    // the salt (in its plaintext form; this is not a security risk).
    $query_params = array(
        ':username' => $_POST['username'],
        ':password' => $password,
        ':salt' => $salt,
        ':email' => $_POST['email']
    );

    try
    {
        // Execute the query to create the user
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
    }
    catch(PDOException $ex)
    {
        // Note: On a production website, you should not output $ex->getMessage().
        // It may provide an attacker with helpful information about your code. 
        die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
    }

    // This redirects the user back to the login page after they register
    header("Location: login.php");

    // Calling die or exit after performing a redirect using the header function
    // is critical.  The rest of your PHP script will continue to execute and
    // will be sent to the user if you do not die or exit.
    die("Redirecting to login.php");
}
?>
```

That is my PHP code. Below is my HTML code. Please tell me my mistake so I can make sure to change it.

Now since there is an issue with not all HTMl tags being supported in Stackoverflow, I have posted it in pastebin.

http://pastebin.com/rB8zQAdP

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you don't exit the program when the error occurs so it keeps running and executes the query.

You may try to add an extra variable that determines if there is an error and you just skip the mysql query.

```
$isError = false;
if(empty($username))
{
   $isError = true;
}

if($isError)
{
    // Handle error
}else{
    // Execute query
}
```

Or put all your if statements into a php function and throw an exception when an error occurs and handle it with a try{} catch() statement.

```
function TestSomething($username)
{
  if(empty($username))
    throw new Exception("No username");
}

try
{
  TestSomething("");
  // Execute query
}catch(Exception $ex)
{
  // Handle error
  echo $ex->getMessage(); // Prints no username
}
```

But you may put a "throw new Exception("Message")" into your try statement and it will stop executing the program and jump to the catch statement.

Answer (score 0):

It's still registering your information because you never stop executing if an error is encountered.  How you go about doing it can vary depending on if you only want to show a single error message or all error messages back to the user, but a possible simple solution could be something like below:

```
$error = false;
if(empty($_POST['username'])) {
    $error = "Please enter a username";
}

if(empty($_POST['password'])) {
    $error = "Please enter a password";
}

// .. further validation ..

if(!$error) {
    // Insert new user
} else {
    // Redirect back to form with error message(s) set
}
```

Comment: Would that way show all the error messages to the user or the single? I would like to display all the errors at once.

Comment: That way will only show one.  To show multiple, make `$errors` an array and pass that back to the form.